# Late 2011 Macbook Pro 15" built in trackpad going haywire

Tags: mac, macbook-pro

Admittedly I cleaned the laptops body the other day paying no mind to the fact that I was using a slightly damn towelette like rag. Since then the trackpad has become hyper-sensitive at times, sluggish at other times, and if I am watching a movie or something, seems to have a mind of its own.

I have cleaned my laptop like this before without issue, not to say that its justified but just saying it regardless. That said I have tried to reset my PRAM in and out of safe mode, and when I do it appears to work fine for a while, even placing my palm over the trackpad for some seconds seems to work for a short time, but in all it seems to stupify again and again.

Anything from the mouse jittery jumping across the screen by itself, to sometimes selecting text while I am typing and having a little white box with a definition of the word showing up. So something is glitching somewhere somehow but I dunno what where when or how.

So I am trying to figure out how to determin if I have to replace something physically or reset something somehow in a way I havent tried, or what. I figure someone with better knowlege of Mac than I have can maybe assist me.

Answer (score 2):

Try using electrical contact cleaner and a brand new unused cloth. Don't use a lot, just a couple of short sprays. - Get the contact cleaner from most electrical component stores. The cloth you used to clean may of had something else on it previously, in my case - WD40 which took ages to get off and made the trackpad unusable. Don't use the trackpad at all for a few hours. Just get by with a USB mouse for now.